# How to use zip in this case or any other solution?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I have an input like this:

```
Input = {1: [array([5, 2, 1, 10, 2, 1]), array([20, 2, 10, 1, 2, 1])], 2: [array([44, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3])}
```

I am looking for output like this:

```
Output = (5, 20, 44), (2, 2, 1), (1, 10, 1), (10, 1, 4), (2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 3)
```

I tried zip of Python but it's not working, seems like I am wrong somewhere. Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: First, read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: your question is not clear at all.

Comment: Sorry I tried posting but it was not allowing me so I removed the code. 
This is what is the question is:
I have an input like this:
Input = {1: [array([5,  2,  1,  1,  2,  1]), array([20,  2,  10,  1,  2,  1])], 2: [array([44,  1,  1,  4,  3,  3]), array([79,  1,  1,  4,  3,  3])]}

I need output like this:
Output - (5, 20, 44, 79), (2, 2, 1, 1), etc.

I tried using zip of Python but somehow it’s not working. Can anyone please help?

Please do let me know if any information is needed.

Comment: @user18326231 [edit] your question to add the code in. Once you have pasted the code in, highlight the code and click the `{}` button in order to format it properly

Comment: @user18326231 Do the arrays all have the same length? If not, then this becomes a considerably trickier task

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you all please check now?

Comment: @BenGrossmann all the arrays are of same length

Comment: Can you show an example of the actual input data you're dealing with. What you've shown so far is syntactically flawed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

Input = {1: [array([5, 2, 1, 10, 2, 1]), array([20, 2, 10, 1, 2, 1])], 2: array([44, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3])}
Output = [tuple(row) for row in np.vstack([*Input.values()]).T]
print(Output)
```

Result:

```
[(5, 20, 44), (2, 2, 1), (1, 10, 1), (10, 1, 4), (2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 3)]
```

---

An approach using only builtin methods:

```
Input = {1: [array([5, 2, 1, 10, 2, 1]), array([20, 2, 10, 1, 2, 1])], 2: [array([44, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3])]}

rows = []
for a in Input.values():
    for row in a:
        rows.append(list(row))
Output = [*zip(*rows)]
print(Output)
```

Result:

```
[(5, 20, 44), (2, 2, 1), (1, 10, 1), (10, 1, 4), (2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 3)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it would be helpful if I can get it with python inbuilt libraries.

Comment: @user18326231 But the dictionary you defined already uses numpy. Do you want to replace the numpy arrays with lists too?

Comment: I checked but I am only using pandas.

Comment: @user18326231 Also for future reference, if you want a method that uses particular libraries, then that is context you should include explicitly in your question.

Comment: @user18326231 It's strange that you'd want to use pandas but numpy. In any case, would a solution that uses pandas be acceptable?

Comment: Sure, I will remember that. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Grossman No, please suggest with in built libraries only. Can't we use Zip?

Comment: @user18326231 Your input is using *array* but you say you only want to use built-ins. Can you explain that? Pure Python doesn't have a built-in array function

Comment: @Olvin Roght, when I iterated a dataset, I received the output as this array but I have only used pandas. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user18326231 See my edit.

Comment: @BenGrossmann yeah, that works. Thank you so much. That was pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this although there may be a better way of implementing my so-called *magic* function:

```
from numpy import array
Input = {1: [array([5, 2, 1, 10, 2, 1]), array([20, 2, 10, 1, 2, 1])], 2: array([44, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3])}
def magic(d):
    result = []
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            result.extend(v)
        else:
            result.append(v)
    return result

print(', '.join(str(x) for x in zip(*magic(Input))))
```

**Output:**

```
(5, 20, 44), (2, 2, 1), (1, 10, 1), (10, 1, 4), (2, 2, 3), (1, 1, 3)
```